# What are the differences between C208 versions?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-identification, cessna-208

I am aware of a few versions of C208:

- C208 Caravan
- C208 Grand Caravan
- C208 Grand Caravan Amphibian

Amphibian has pantoons with retractable landing gears, but what is the difference between C208 Caravan and C208 Grand Caravan? Is it just the cargo compartment in the belly? Are there other versions of C208? What are the differences between them?

Comment: A search for 'Cessna 208' would have found you [this Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_208_Caravan) that contains a list of variants (civil and military) together with notes on their differences. I'm not going to cut and paste that here.

Answer (score 4):

The civilian variants can be summed up in this table I made based on Wikipedia:

[image]

What to take out of this, is the different fuselage lengths, and that the amphibian comes in two fuselage lengths.

The belly-mounted cargo-hold is optional.

There are also military variants, even one that shoots missiles (an incentive to check out [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_208_Caravan#Variants)).

Comment: The difference between Caravan and Grand caravan is 4 Feet in lenght. I guess, this is what OP is expecting. Regarding the Base caravan, i dont think, cessna makes them anymore. the only option seems to be the PT6 in 675HP version.